# How to denote quartiles so as not to be confused with quarterly data

Tags: quantiles, notation

Is there an existing statistical notation convention that can make clear that can only be interpreted as quartiles? To my knowledge, quartile notation is the same with quarterly data notation:

```
Q1, Q2, Q3...
```

One difference being that typically Q4 is omitted for quartiles, but this difference is too subtle. Imagine a reader saw these labels on the x axis on a graph. Context could help, but I'd rather not have to have the reader connect the dots too much for him/herself. I'd want to make it as clear as possible that I mean quartiles.

Is the only alternative to spell it out?

Comment: How about replacing Q2 with median?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$q_x$ is quite common notation for an $x$ quantile. The quartiles would be $q_{0.25}$, $q_{0.5}$ (the median) and $q_{0.75}$. You could also suppress the leading zero if you feel this makes things more legible: $q_{.25}$, $q_{.5}$ and $q_{.75}$.